# Laravel: Trying to get property of non-object when taking data via foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a `User` and a `Tag` model. Both are linked by a 1:N relation.

I am trying to take col `tag_name` from `user` model. However I am receiving this error:

> Trying to get Trying to get property 'tag_name' of non-object.

User model has

```
 // linking with table tag
public function tags(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Tag');
}
```

Tag model has

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}
```

My view has

```
 {{ Form::checkbox('tag[]',$user->tag_id,['class'=>'cats']) }}
 {{ Form::label('tb',$user->tag_id->tag_name,['class'=>'btn btncategory']) }}
```

Controller has the following in index function

```
 $user = User::find($user_id);
 return view('user.create_post')->with('user', $user );
```

Route:

```
Route::get('create', 'PostsController@index');
```

Please help me where I am wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To clarify. A user has a single tag and each tag can be associated with multiple users right?

Comment: yeah for now. Because i am just testing. Later i would change to users can have any number of tags and vice versa

Comment: for that i would make both relations N:N has Many() both right?

Comment: I suggest you do that now. There's a big difference between 1:N and M:N relationships in that M:N relationships need an extra pivot table which and need to be handled differently. You will find that implementing a 1:N and then switching to M:N is not easy. To implement that you will put `belongsToMany` for both models and will need to have a loop e.g. `foreach ($user->tags as $tag)` to access each user tag. Also it would be good to get the user as `User::with('tags')->find($id)` to eager load them

Comment: Ohh okay, thanks for that.  btw can you explain User::with('tags')->find($id). This would filter as per tags? Sorry for such questions. I am new to laravel

Comment: `$user = User::with('tags')->find($id)` will ensure that `$user->tags` is populated when the user is read from the database. If you don't use that then you might need to do `$tags=$user->tags()->get()` instead to *lazy load* the tags. In your case if you need them immediately you should eager load them, if not then lazy load them when and if you need them

Comment: .tag_user' doesn't exist (SQL: select `tags`.*, `tag_user`.`user_user_id` as `pivot_user_user_id`, `tag_user`.`tag_tag_id` as `pivot_tag_tag_id` from `tags` inner join `tag_user` on `tags`.`tag_id` = `tag_user`.`tag_tag_id` where `tag_user`.`user_user_id` in (1))

Comment: it gives this error now

Comment: As I said, if you switch to an M:N relationship you need a pivot table. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many explains how this table should look like as well as the naming conventions

Comment: okay, thanks for this.. Can you help me solving this error i am getting. The one i asked in question, non-object one

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `user` has multiple `tags` you need to loop through each of them:

In blade file:

```
@foreach ($user->tags as $tag) 
    <label class="btn btncategory">
        <input type="checkbox" name=tag[] value="{{$tag->id}}" class="cats" />
        {{$tag->name}}
    </label>
@endforeach
```

Now when you submit this you should have all checked tags in the array `request()->input('tag')`

Note I've removed the `Form::` because I like to put the checkboxes inside the label but you can just use the `Form::` style if you want like below:

```
@foreach ($user->tags as $tag) 
   {{ Form::checkbox('tag[]',$tag->id,['class' => 'cats']) }}
   {{ Form::label('tb',$tag->name,['class' => 'btn btncategory']) }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: After trying this, i get error: Property [tags] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: "collection instance" ? Are you sure `$user` is the result of `User::find($id)` ?